# Securing Express route with JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization

I am new to JWT authentication and I need to secure an Express route. Before adding the auth I did the following to return an HTML page using Express:

```
var cache = {};

app.get('/my_page', function (req, res) {
    serveStatic(res, cache, './public/default/my_page.html');
});
```

where serveStatic is:

```
var send404 = function (response) {
    response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('Error 404: Resource not found.');
    response.end();
}

var sendFile = function(response, filePath, fileContents) {
    var mimeType = mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath));
    response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": mimeType});
    response.end(fileContents);
}

var serveStatic = function(response, cache, absPath) {
    if (cache[absPath]) {
        sendFile(response, absPath, cache[absPath]);
    } else {
        fs.exists(absPath, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        send404(response);
                    } else {
                        cache[absPath] = data; // Cache the file
                        sendFile(response, absPath, data); // Serve the file
                    }
                });
            } else {
                send404(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Users clicked a button to access the page: `<button type="button" onclick="window.location='my_page'">Go</button>`

I added authentication as follows:

```
// In /middleware/auth file
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header("Authorization");

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth Error",
            errorCode: 401,
            redirectUrl: "/"
        });
    }
    
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.user = decoded.user;
        next();
    } catch (e) {        
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Invalid Token",
            errorCode: 500,
            redirectUrl: "/"
        });
    }
};
```

I changed the route management as:

```
const auth = require("./middleware/auth");

app.get('/licenses',
    auth,
    function (req, res, next) {
        serveStatic(res, cache, './public/default/my_page.html');
    }
);
```

and I changed the button onclick to call a function that retrieves the JWT from the cookie and sends it with the request.

```
<button type="button" onclick="openPage()">Go</button>
```

```
var openPage= function() {
    if (document.cookie != "") {
        var token = getCookie("token");

        if (token != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/my_page",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token); 
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    
                },
                error: function($xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error('token is empty');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('cookie is empty');
    }
}
```

The auth process is fine, but the client receives a message containing the my_page.html code in its responseText property. Is there a way to make it behave like it was before I added the auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that at the beginning, you were redirecting the browser to the `/my_page` endpoint. So the browser was receiving the whole HTML web page as the `payload` of the `HTTP` request and rendering on the page. Then, you change that behavior for an AJAX request, allowing fetching data from the server without refreshing the page.

> AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files. AJAX’s most appealing characteristic is its "asynchronous" nature, which means it can communicate with the server, exchange data, and update the page without refreshing the page.
> _From MDN WebDocs [Ajax/Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

You might revert the way you redirect your clients to what you were doing before (though using an anchor tag would be best), but that wouldn't solve your problem. The authorization middleware will reject the requests because it can't find a JWT on the `Authentication` header.

Nonetheless, from your implementation of the `openPage` function, I see that you have the JWT token already stored inside a `cookie`. Cookies are sent along with every request to the server. It would be best if you tried modifying your authentication middleware to get the JWT token from the cookies and not from the `Authentication` header.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I replaced the AJAX call as it was before and retrieved the token from the cookie.